# sbt-web-plugin: specifying classpath to jetty with configurationXml

Tags: jetty, sbt, xsbt-web-plugin

I trying to create custom configuration for jetty when using sbt-web-plugin (for running with `container:start`). There are [two container settings](https://github.com/siasia/xsbt-web-plugin/wiki/Settings) allowing to specify custom jetty xml configuration: `configurationFiles` and `configurationXml` (when `customConfiguration` is true).

However, this overrides internal configuration of jetty done by sbt-web-plugin completely so custom config should configure jetty fully. And it will not work without specifying classpath to .class files compiled from project and to dependencies.

I trying to do something like that:

```
configurationXml in container.Configuration <<= fullClasspath (
  <Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
    ...
    <Set name="handler">
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
        <Set name="resourceBase"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/src/main/webapp</Set>
        <Set name="descriptor"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</Set>
        <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
        <Set name="extraClasspath">{/* classpath should be here */}</Set>
      </New>
    </Set>
    ...
  </Configure>
)
```

Seems that direct dependency of `configurationXml` on `fullClasspath` is not possible, because [`configurationXml` is `SettingKey`](https://github.com/siasia/xsbt-web-plugin/blob/fe9ea5388c73ad4e8d28fd244e074322e023c9b5/src/main/scala/com/github/siasia/PluginKeys.scala#L26) and [`fullClasspath` is `TaskKey`](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/blob/v0.12.0/main/Keys.scala#L237):

> [Tasks with dependencies](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/More-About-Settings.html#tasks-with-dependencies)
>
> The practical importance of this is that you can't have tasks as dependencies for a non-task setting.

Is it possible to include `fullClasspath` setting in `configurationXml` parameter?

If not, is it still possible to add custom configuration settings to jetty development server invoked on `container:start`?

Answer (score 2):

You can customize just the `WebAppContext` using the `env` setting:

```
env in Compile := Some(file(".") / "jetty-env.xml" asFile)
```

For example, consider the following in *myproject/jetty-env.xml*:

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/custom</Set>
</Configure>
```

This will deploy your webapp under the context path */custom*, but won't change any configuration of the underlying `Server`.

Comment: Where is this `env` setting documented?

Comment: You can find it in the [docs for version 0.9](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/blob/master/docs/0.9.md#web-application-settings), but that's pretty old and deprecated.  I'll look into updating this for 2.1.